# Ethereum and dApps real life benefits

Tags: ether, dapp-development, dapps

I've been reading about Ethereum and it's fundamentals for a while now. I am familiar with blockchain and secure data concept. Completely secure data is awesome and I find it very interesting. What I am struggling with is trying to find some real life use cases where dApps could make actual difference, where dApps have potential to achieve something completely new. I've found a lot of articles how dApps will change the world but most articles have basic logic errors in them. Can you please give me real benefits of using dApps compared to creating traditional (for example relational) database with proper security? Removing middleman (e.g. middleman between photographer and photo buyer) is not argument because for average Joe it doesn't matter if he/she has to pay fees to Ethereum network or to middleman to process. And after all, he/she has to use some interface and someone has to create that same user interface and program backend logic into dApp. Also average Joe doesn't care if the technology uses some sql or blockchain, he only cares about getting his things done. 
Is Ethereum smart contract real value in being trustworthy for those who can read smart contracts code? And even in this case, trustworthy only wants to be someone who is not yet, so big corporations are not potential users? I mean big banks, car dealers, e-shops etc, we trust them anyway no matter if they do or do not use dApps. 
Can dApps do something completely new, something that wasn't possible before? It would be great if you could provide me with examples.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your problem is that you do not see the benefit of a trustless system, and that your question is essentially, "Why does it matter that a payment system be trustless?"

The 'real-life benefit' of Ethereum is that your money is secure, there is no central authority dictating its value (e.g. setting interest rates, creating money at will through debt creation, fractional reserve banking), and reading code you do not need to trust anyone: Simply put, the opportunity for corruption is minimized, and power is transferred from bankers and politicians to the common man.

"The common man doesn't read smart contracts," you object. Ethereum is a paradigm shift restoring control over one's money to owner: It may be that the ability to read code is in the 21st century as important as being able to read books from the 16th century. If you are illiterate, then you should become literate or be economically at a disadvantage. (Already the common man is declaring to have read terms of service agreements, and these are not much less complicated.)

To me the benefits of Ethereum are clear: Transactions can be automated without a need to trust a company (increasing the efficiency and convenience of life and decreasing risk of fraud) and value is secure from politicians and bankers interested only in making themselves wealthy.